# Border expands div height

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with borders in css, they are set to hidden on normal state and 1px on hover. The result is this:

[image]

On mouseover, the lower row gets pushed down by 1px. I've tried to add `box-sizing:border-box`, but that didn't help.

```
.menu-sidebar {

    margin-top:25px;
}

.iconmenutest{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:rgba(40,40,40,0.9);
    color:gray;
    border:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.iconmenutest:hover  {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    background: rgba(40,40,40,0.3);
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

Here's the html:

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="menu-sidebar row">
            <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                <div class="iconmenu">
                    <i class="ion-power"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                <div class="iconmenu">
                    <i class="ion-alert-circled"></i>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                <div class="iconmenu">
                    <i class="ion-android-add"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                  <div class="iconmenu">
                      <i class="ion-power"></i>
                   </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                   <div class="iconmenu">
                       <i class="ion-alert-circled"></i>
                   </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                   <div class="iconmenu">
                       <i class="ion-android-add"></i>
                   </div>
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                   <div class="iconmenu">
                        <i class="ion-power"></i>
                   </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                  <div class="iconmenu">
                        <i class="ion-alert-circled"></i>
                  </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 iconmenutest">
                   <div class="iconmenu">
                        <i class="ion-android-add"></i>
                   </div>
             </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

What should I do to keep layout without the grey line you see on the picture?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting it to "hidden" (i guess you meant to 0px), set it to transparent with the same width

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

Comment: You've been too quick - can accept in 11 minutes..  :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two great options to work with this

1. **Transparent border**

dont set hidden border use transparent color,so it will remain there but not be visible

```
border: 1px dotted transparent;
```

2. **Use Outline**

Set outline instead of border in hover

```
 outline: 1px dotted gray;
```

> The outline is not a part of the element's dimensions, therefore the
>   element's width and height properties do not contain the width of the
>   outline.